# Error when Input is : C:\src\flutter>flutter doctor

Tags: flutter

On setting up Flutter:

error :CreateProcessW failed 193
       CreateProcessW failed 193
       Unhandled exception:
       ProcessException: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

i have Tried changing username

Comment: Are you using Powershell to start Flutter doctor?

Comment: Similar to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19359, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15014

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen yes I am using powershell.

Answer (score 0):

from the Command prompt run the flutter doctor inside the flutter installation directory:

```
 C:\src\flutter> flutter doctor
```